# Route with PHP F3 matching an "http://..." adress

Tags: php, url, routes, fat-free-framework

I am working with PHP F3. I have some issues with their routing engine.

Let say my website is [www.test.com](http://www.test.com), I would like to have a special handler when I enter this url : [www.test.com/https://www.google.com/](http://www.test.com/https://www.google.com/)

I want to get the "https://www.google.com/" part and store it in a database.

For now I have this route:
`GET /*=Page->myHandler`

which is not working when there are :, ., ?, etc symbols

My guess is to rewrite a special routing function for this case but how to bypass the existing one ?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it's directly working against how the regex for the routing engine is parsing things in the `Base->run()` method. If I were to make a recommendation I would put your endpoint as something like `myapp.com/incoming-url?url=[the url encoded URL you want to save in the database]` If it's not URL encoded, even the browser will have a tough time figuring out what you want to do.